# HTML 5 drag drop - Using custom cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am actually trying to use a custom cursor when dragover operation of HTML 5 Drag-drop API is happening, but I am not able to do override the default cursor when dragover event is triggered. Here is the code of how I try to achieve it,

```
$("#myDiv").live('mousedown', function(ev) {
  $(this).css("cursor", "url(res/customCursor.cur), default !important");
});
```

Since the mouse would be pressed when dragover event is happening, I try to change cursor in mousedown event of the target of drag-drop. I also have tried to change the cursor in event handler of dragover event, but even that doesn't work.

Comment: `!important` works fine in a stylesheet, or an inline style (except IE6), but not when setting  styles in JavaScript or jQuery. In that case, styles with `!important` won't get applied in Firefox, Chrome, and IE8 or earlier.

Comment: why not make a class and apply it to the dragged element using the addClass method in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet definitions (<style> element or .css file) create a class like

```
.dragAndDropInProgress {
  cursor: url(....), default !important; 
}
```

and then when you signal the ondragstart, attach that class to the document body, making sure to remove it again once you see the ondragend.

Comment: While this solves the problem of !important only working in stylesheets, it does not solve the OP's original problem which is overriding drag and drop cursors, which seem to take priority over CSS styles.